# Is Telerik mobile app running in AppBuilder or as packaged app?

Tags: telerik-appbuilder

I'm developing my first mobile app using the Telerik platform and I'm trying to find a way of dynamically setting the configuration based on the environment that the code is running in. e.g.:

```
var apiUrl;

function setConfig()
{
  if (window.navigator.simulator)
  {
    // Debug in simulator
    apiUrl = "http://localhost:1234/api/myapp";  
  }
  else if ( ??? )
  {
    // System Testing
    apiUrl = "https://beta.myapp.com/api/myapp";  
  } 
  else {
    // Production
    apiUrl = "https://myapp.com/api/myapp";  
  }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is tell if the application is running within Telerik's AppBuilder mobile app, which I'm using for system testing, or as a packaged application (production app)

I've had a trawl through Telerik's javascript API, but can't see anything that seems to fit the bill, and I don't expect to find anything in the Cordova API since this is specific to the Telerik platform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with debug and release-specific files inside of AppBuilder ([see the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/build-configurations/configuration-specific-files)). This allows you to target debug files for your debug (i.e. test) builds and release files for your release (i.e. app store) builds.